# Mysql connector - How to use connection pool with multiple databases?

Tags: python, mysql, multiple-databases, connection-pool

I have more than 30 databases and I want to use connection pool in my python code.

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=MYSQL_HOST,
        user=MYSQL_USERNAME,
        passwd=MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        database=database,
        charset='utf8',
        use_unicode=True,
        pool_name='connection_pool',
        pool_size=10
)
```

In API calls, based on sub-domain, I have to decide which database to connect.
For example "abc.mydomain.com", so I have to connect to abc's database. It is working fine with a single connection but It's taking time each time it tries to connect to the database.

Comment: use utf8mb4 not utf8 before you get corrupted strings. You can use `USE {database}` to switch the default database eon a connection. Database connections should be quick. Do you have 'skip-name-resolve' enabled on the server? Are you database user users created by IP, domain name of host, or '%'?

Comment: "I have more than 30 databases" What!? Please explain!

Comment: @KlausD. I'm building a SaaS-based product where I'm using a separate database for each customer. For testing, I'm using 30 databases.

Comment: @danblack Yes, I have --skip-name-resolve enabled. And Yes, users created by IP, domain name of host, or '%'

Comment: how much time is the connection taking?

Comment: more than 200ms

Comment: Sometimes, it's taking 130ms. conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=MYSQL_HOST,
            user=MYSQL_USERNAME,
            passwd=MYSQL_PASSWORD,
            charset='utf8mb4',
            use_unicode=True,
            pool_name='connection_pool',
            pool_size=10
        )

Comment: Any solution guys?

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but, you want a connection pool for 30 databases, since it is taking time to break and establish a new connection, it is better to establish 30 different connection pools for 30 connections and store them in dictionary based on database name, and from my research a connection pool can only store a single database connection and even if we try add multiple db connections to it, when we try to access one of them, there is a half half chance of getting either one, so it is more efficient to use multiple connection pools.